# Remove user and password in Gentoo

Tags: users, gentoo

My friend gives me Gentoo [installed yet].
I virtualized it on virtual box but my friend doesn't remember User and Password and he says me there is a method to remove user and password but he doesn't remember what this method is. 
How can I do this? 
In alternative, is there a method to create another account without touch that one?

Comment: How did your friend "give"  you gentoo? on a drive? on a usb?